# Working out how many items to take in a paginated list

Tags: c#, math, pagination

I'm trying to work this out but for the life of I cannot!

I am calling an API that is paged, each page has 20 items. I am attempting to implement infinite scroll on my UI to use the data from this API and we load 12 items at a time, so I need to work out what page number I need to take from and how many to take in that API.

For Example:

I currently am at item 10 and I want to take 20 more items, that means I need to take 10 items from Page 1 and then 10 items from Page 2. But I cannot work out how to do this!

This is the model I'm working with:

```
public class PagesToLoad
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int Take { get; set; }
    public int Skip { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the method signature

```
public static List<PagesToLoad> GetPage(int currentlyLoaded, int toLoad, int maxItemsPerPage)
```

I would show you what I've tried but it's pointless since I can't work out how to do it.

A few examples:

currentlyLoaded = 0 and I want to load 12 and the `maxItemsPerPage` is 20.
So the results should be:

```
new List<PagesToLoad>
{
    new PagesToLoad
    {
        Page = 1,
        Skip = 0,
        Take = 12
    },
}
```

currentlyLoaded = 10 and I want to load 20 and the `maxItemsPerPage` is 20.
So the results should be:

```
new List<PagesToLoad>
{
    new PagesToLoad
    {
        Page = 1,
        Skip = 10,
        Take = 10
    },
    new PagesToLoad
    {
        Page = 2,
        Take = 10,
        Skip = 0
    }
}
```

Update:

I have wrote some unit tests to attempt to test some of these scenarios using NUnit.
The below tests only currently test that it's returning the correct page that we should be taking from, and does not currently test for the correct position on the current page

```
[TestCaseSource(nameof(TestData))]
public void TestPaginationPagesToLoad(int currentlyLoaded, int toLoad, int maxItemsPerPage, int[] expectedPages)
{
    var result = PaginationHelper.GetNextPages(currentlyLoaded, toLoad, maxItemsPerPage);
    var pages = result.Select(x => x.Page).ToArray();

    Assert.That(pages.Length, Is.EqualTo(expectedPages.Length), "Did not contain the correct amount of pages");
    for (int i = 0; i < pages.Length; i++)
    {
        Assert.That(pages[i], Is.EqualTo(expectedPages[i]));
    }


}

public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestData
{
    get
    {

            yield return new TestCaseData(0, 10, 20,  new [] { 1 }).SetName("Load_First_Page");
            yield return new TestCaseData(20, 10, 20, new [] { 2 }).SetName("Load_Second_Page");
            yield return new TestCaseData(0, 20, 20,  new [] { 1 }).SetName("Load_Full_First_Page");
            yield return new TestCaseData(20, 20, 20, new [] { 2 }).SetName("Load_Full_Second_Page");
            yield return new TestCaseData(10, 20, 20, new [] { 1, 2 }).SetName("Load_Half_First_Page_And_Half_Second_Page");
            yield return new TestCaseData(19, 20, 20, new [] { 1, 2 }).SetName("Load_End_First_Page_And_Most_Second_Page");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page n contains items (sn - s + 1) through sn, inclusive on both end, where s is the number of items per page. Suppose you are at item m and want to take k more items. Then you want to take items m + 1, m + 2, …, m + k. The first page you need to look at is (m + 1 - 1) / s + 1, where division is integer division (just the quotient, no remainder). On that page, you need to start taking from (m + 1 - 1) % s + 1 and on, where % is the remainder after division (modulus). The last page you'll need to look at is (m + k - 1) / s + 1, and you'll need to look up to (m + k - 1) % s + 1.

Your example:

```
s = 20
m = 10
k = 20
first page:   (m + 1 - 1) / s + 1
            = (10 + 1 - 1) / 20 + 1
            = 10 / 20 + 1
            = 0 + 1 = 1


start pos:    (m + 1 - 1) % s + 1
            = (10 + 1 - 1) % 20 + 1
            = 10 % 20 + 1
            = 10 + 1 = 11

last page:    (m + k - 1) / s + 1
            = (10 + 20 - 1) / 20 + 1
            = 29/20 + 1
            = 1 + 1 = 2


stop pos:     (m + k - 1) % s + 1
            = (10 + 20 - 1) % 20 + 1
            = 29 % 20 + 1
            = 9 + 1 = 10
```

Note that if `last page > first page + 1`, you'll need to get the entirety of the pages in between.

EDIT: adding some C#, might even work!

```
List<PagesToLoad> GetPagesToload(int curItemIndex, int numItemsToGet, int itemsPerPage)
{
    List<PagesToLoad> result = new List<pagesToLoad>();

    int firstPage = curItemIndex / itemsPerPage + 1;
    int startPos = curItemIndex % itemsPerPage + 1;

    int lastItemIndex = curItemIndex + numItemsToGet - 1;
    int lastPage = lastItemIndex / itemsPerPage + 1;
    int stopPos = lastItemIndex % itemsPerPage + 1;

    PagesToLoad page1 = new PagesToLoad();
    page1.Page = firstPage;
    page1.Skip = curItemIndex;
    page1.Take = numItemsToGet;

    if (numItemsToGet + startPos - 1 > itemsPerPage)
    {
        page1.Take = itemsPerPage - startPos + 1;
        result.Add(page1);

        for (int i = firstPage + 1; i < lastPage; i++)
        {
            PagesToAdd nextPage = new PagesToAdd();
            nextPage.Page = i;
            nextPage.Skip = 0;
            nextPage.Take = itemsPerPage;
            result.Add(nextPage);
        }

        PagesToAdd pageN = new PagesToAdd();
        pageN.Page = lastPage;
        pageN.Skip = 0;
        pageN.Take = stopPos;
        result.Add(pageN);
    }
    else
    {
        result.Add(page1);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I did not test this code or even try to compile it - but this might give you enough of an idea to get it right.

Comment: @JamieRees I will try to add some C# :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, that has put me on the correct track :)